# How can i generate JSON schema with a required filed or default values?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

im using jackson to handle JSON objects, and i want a way to generate a schema from a class that i can enforce on the objects.
i found out that i can use this :

```
JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(DBUser.class);
mapper.writeValueAsString(jsonSchema);
```

using this com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jsonSchema.JsonSchemaGenerator.
generated from this class:

```
public class DBUser {

    private String database="stu";
    private int role;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    //setters and getters defined
    }
```

which gives me this :

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:DBUser",
  "properties" : {
    "database" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "role" : {
      "type" : "integer"
    },
    "username" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "password" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

what i need is a required field like this :

```
"required": ["database","role","username"]
```

but  it has no required field, or initial values, which i need.
so how can i get that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can annotate your pojo `DBUser` class fields with the [`JsonProperty#required`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required()) set to `true` to generate a jsonschema with required fields:

```
public class DBUser {

    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String database = "stu";
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private int role;
    @JsonProperty(required = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
}

//generate the new jsonschema with the required fields
JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(DBUser.class);
System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                         .writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));


//json generated
{
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "urn:jsonschema:DBUser",
  "properties" : {
    "database" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "required" : true
    },
    "role" : {
      "type" : "integer",
      "required" : true
    },
    "username" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "required" : true
    },
    "password" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that according to the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema) the jsonschema module supports the creation of a JSON Schema (v3) and not upper JSON Schema versions, so keywords introduced in later versions are not supported.

Comment: thanks this is great !, but what about adding a default value ?

Comment: @AwsAbuObeid You are welcome, unfortunately the `default` keyword has been added in one of the later versions (probably v7) so it has not been included in the library.

Comment: downvoted this bc OP wants to required field to read `"required": ["database","role","username"]` as opposed to given `"required" : true` per property.

Comment: @daniel.kahlenberg I'm agree OP wanted a slightly different output but  `jackson` supports  json schema v3 while array of required values has been introduced in the v4, you can check [draft-03-to-draft-04](https://github.com/json-schema/json-schema/wiki/Change-Log:-draft-03-to-draft-04).